# Can I say a ligament has been ruptured?

Tags: word-usage

In basketball, when you tear your achilles tendon, it can be said that it has been "ruptured." I understand what rupture means, so in the same context, can I say, I ruptured my ACL? In sports, I have never seen anybody (at least not to my knowledge) say I "ruptured" my ACL, it is always I tore my ACL. Is there any reason why I cannot say I ruptured my ACL instead of tearing my ACL.

Disclaimer, I have not suffered any injury. I am just wondering as during basketball season, I have seen many people tear their ACL but never "ruptured."

Comment: Tendons can also become _detached_ (pulled loose from the bone).  I hate it when that happens.  Spent 9 months in therapy after my operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tear and rupture seem to be interchangeable https://coastalorthopedics.com/differences-tear-rupture/ . Seems like a rupture is the same as saying a complete tear. Perhaps partial tears of ligaments are more common than of tendons, so 'tear' is more widely used.